# Put objects from collection on "floor" with Geometry Nodes (Alignment of objects from collection)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a collection of objects, some of them have some Z height and some have scale.
I want to spread them and have them sit "on the floor" (align them on lowest point)
I tried to use Bounding Box node to get the lowest point of each instance but all I get is (0,0,0) for all of them.
How can I achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Bounding Box* does not return any positions for instances, which is why you would have to realize the instances first.

But to get the lowest point per object, you can remove all faces of the *Bounding Box*, convert the remaining downward pointing faces into points, and transfer the Z-position from them:

[image]

*PS: Of course you can also use the node `Translate Instances` instead of `Set Position`. In this case the result will be the same.*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: You are a magician!

Comment: @YanivGershoni You are welcome! ;-)